# Angular/Typescript - Easy way to append items to every array in a list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a *formTemplate* array which contains list of *fields*. I want to append few default item to each fields list.
I was able to achieve it with the following code. But I want to know whether we have any easy way or Linq expression to do the same.

```
    AppendDefaultFields(){
       for (var i = 0; i < this.formTemplate.length; i++) {
          this.formTemplate[i].fields = [this.renderDefaultFields('EmployeeId'), this.renderDefaultFields('HireDate'), ...this.formTemplate[i].fields];
        }
     }

renderDefaultFields(fieldName: string) {
    return {
      id: 1,
      title: fieldName,
      type: 'string',
      mandatory: false,
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could neaten the code using `forEach` on the array, and you could use `splice` to insert the extra fields instead of spread notation. By the way, inserting at the start is called prepending - appending means adding at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise approach would be:

- Iterate with `for..of` instead of over the indicies manually
- Map an array of the `fieldNames` to prepend instead of calling `this.renderDefaultFields` for both

```
AppendDefaultFields(){
    for (const t of this.formTemplate) {
        t.fields = ['EmployeeId', 'HireDate']
            .map(this.renderDefaultFields)
            .concat(t.fields);
    }
}
```

The `.map(this.renderDefaultFields)`, which would usually be suspect, works here because you're not referencing `this` inside the `renderDefaultFields` method. If you did need to reference `this` inside it, you'd either need to use a class field to define the method instead, or `.bind` in the constructor`, or something similar.

Comment: Both the methods are working. Also the below methods were also working.

`this.formTemplate.map(t => t.fields = [this.renderDefaultFields('EmployeeId'), this.renderDefaultFields('HireDate'), ...t.fields]);`
or
`this.formTemplate.map(t => t.fields = ['EmployeeId', 'HireDate']
         .map(this.renderDefaultFields)
         .concat(t.fields));`

But which one should I choose, which method is efficient ?